# Linq to Sharepoint "where" clause cannot be found

Tags: linq, sharepoint, linq-to-sharepoint

Hello stackoverflowers,

I'm trying to use LINQ to Sharepoint for the first time, but my where keyword isn't recognized : "Could not find an implementation of the query pattern for source type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.SPList'.  'Where' not found".

Here is the request :

```
using System.Linq;
[...]
  var query = from item in listToQuery
              where item.Site == _siteToQuery
              && item.ReportType == _recordTypeToQuery
              && item.Date == stringDate
              select item;
  Result = listToQuery.GetItems(query);
```

listToQuery and Result are two SPListItemCollection.

Why is where not recognized ?

Answer (score 0):

It's normal. The SharePoint Object doesn't implement Linq query, so that's why you have this exception.

To Query a SharePoint List you need to use a **CAML Query** (with an object of type [SPQuery](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spquery) )
you can find a lot of documentation on internet about "how to query a sharepoint list programmatically"

But if you still want to user LINQ on Sharepoint, you can use [SPMetal](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/office/ee538255(v=office.14).aspx)